Can AWS Step Functions host code they execute?
Can I create an AWS Step Function that will not only define the steps it takes, but also defines the code it executes in each step? Or do I need to have a separate resource that is called by the step function to execute my code, like an AWS Lambda?

In general you cannot host code directly in a step function's state.
If you want some logic to be executed in a state, you would usually use a Task state, and include (in the Resource field) a reference to the action that should be executed by that state. The action can be an activity (which is a worker (process or thread), implemented and hosted by you, that performs a specific task), a lambda function, other supported AWS services or an HTTPS API.

A Task state ("Type": "Task") represents a single unit of work performed by a state machine. A task performs work by using an activity or an AWS Lambda function, by integrating with other supported AWS services, or by invoking a HTTPS API, such as Stripe.

(Source)
That said, if your logic involves a relatively simple transformation of a state's input into some output (such as string manipulations, filtering the input properties, introducing additional hard-coded or computed properties, etc...), you can use a Pass state, and include the logic that transforms the input into the output in the definition of the state.
For example (taken from here):
You can transform the input:
{
  "georefOf": "Home"
}

to the output:
{
  "georefOf": "Home",
  "coords": {
    "x-datum": 0.381018,
    "y-datum": 622.2269926397355
  }
}

Using the following state definition:
"No-op": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Result": {
    "x-datum": 0.381018,
    "y-datum": 622.2269926397355
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.coords",
  "End": true
}

In addition, the Amazon States Language used by step functions contains JSONPath Intrinsic Functions that can be used to transform the input.
For example, using States.Format this way:
{
  "Parameters": {
    "foo.$": "States.Format('Your name is {}, we are in the year {}', $.name, 2020)"
  }
}

You can transform the input:
{
  "name": "Foo",
  "zebra": "stripe"
}

Into the output:
{
  "foo": "Your name is Foo, we are in the year 2020"
}

You can find a list of the supported functions here (the example was taken from there).
